# What would be the best way to make pictures taken with different cameras to look the same?

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, filters, color-management, instagram

I am working on cleaning up an Instagram page and one problem I have come across is that there are a lot of pictures on that page. They come from different cameras, lighting and focuses and I was hoping to find a way to make them all look similar and build it into the pages brand. I have tried putting a banner near the bottom of the pictures and adding words to it and processing the pictures through some filters on Canva. This looks okay but I was wondering if anyone had any better options I could explore.

Comment: Let’s say you’ve got two pictures, one at noon, one at dusk. They have drastically different lighting. There’s no way around this, and honestly, why even try? So, what do you mean by “similar”?

Comment: The account has been built to accommodate "shoutouts" per se, where someone can send in a picture of there loved ones and we post it for a donation. Is there anything layout related or overarching design related that I could use?

Comment: I am not expecting this to be perfect just looking to find the best solution to make it look more bareable. Also, for not we have a stamp we put on all the pictures but that doesn't really help with the asthetic cause of the large variety of pictures.

Comment: Do people really pay to have someone else's watermark stamped onto their images?

Comment: Stop worrying about making the images look the same. What if someone shoots a selfie, edits it themselves, then pays for the donation and you eff up their image with your auto filter? Satisfied client? Hardly. Instead focus on how people will see the images. Site layout, promotion, branding, image borders or additional info as image or text (think Polaroid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really only one way to do this: pick a style or feel you like, and throw away the images that don't match. Running things through a homogenization filter is not likely to get good results. So, even if they're good, if they don't match, into a shoebox they go.

More importantly, going forward, consciously take pictures that fit that look. If they don't come out like that, discard them — or at least, don't display them on that account.

Just like there's not a "get rich quick" scheme that really works, there's not a "build an artistic brand" scheme either.  To get results that feel authentic, you'll have to do this the *get rich slow* way.

Comment: That would be ideal but I am using this pictures to generate donations through shout outs, people send me a picture, donate and we post it on the site with a stamp on it. Is there anything layout related or even how they are displayed that could be implemented?